# Blueprism FTE Equivalent Graph

Tags: blueprism

I have a FTE graph created which works correctly when looking at one queue. However, I would like to know if it's possible to look at multiple queues in one graph?
I have attempted the below but it brings an empty graph back.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the definition of the SQL stored procedure that is the source for the chart (dbo.BPDS_FTEProductivityComparison), the parameter BPQueueName requires a single queue name. Anything else you will type in will be treated as a Queue Name (and will return no rows if it doesn't match).

If you want the chart to include data from multiple queues, you're going to have to tweak the SP's query.